# How link the same object into both data and program memory of a DSP?

Tags: linker, refactoring, duplicates, sections

I need to put the same object into different memory sections. I'm working on a [DSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor) with separate data and program memory. The `.text` sections are normally stored inside the P-MEM. But I want to store the same code also inside the data memory. It is possible to copy it during run-time, but I think I should also be possible during link time.

This is what I'm looking for, but it's not working since I could not find a "copy" or "duplicate" instruction that would allow to put the same code in different sections.

```
MEMORY
{
/* MAP 1*/

    VECS:     org=0x00000000 len=0x00000400

    PMEM:     org=0x00000400 len=0x0000FC00 

    DMEM:     org=0x80000000 len=0x0000F800
    DMEM_FT:  org=0x8000F800 len=0x00000800 

}

SECTIONS
{

    vectors    > VECS
    .text      > PMEM <----- containing ALL code (also including func1.obj(.text) )
    .bss       > DMEM
    .cinit     > DMEM
    .stack     > DMEM
    .far       > DMEM
    .switch    > DMEM
    .data      > DMEM
    .sysmem    > DMEM
    .const     > DMEM
    .cio       > DMEM
    dmem_mirror: 
    {
        func1.obj(.text)
    }        > DMEM_FT

}
```

If I'm using the linker script above, it's clearly putting the `func1.obj` only inside the `dmem_FT` section (that`s what the linker is supposed to do!), but that is not what I want :-/ . I'm working with the Texas Instruments compiler and linker, but the syntax is the same as on a GCC linker.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the GNU ld manual does not give an obvious solution. One possible solution does come to mind. You could do a partial (ld -r) link of func1.obj, sending all the sections except .text to the special section [/DISCARD/](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Output-Section-Discarding.html#Output-Section-Discarding) and only outputting the .text section to e.g. func1a.obj. Unfortunately, I think you'll see multiple symbol definition errors from the linker when you actually do the final link.

Comment: hm, thats not working :/, i will do it with a copy of the file. after compilation and before linking i do copy the file. Maybe that the only simple solution